# Why is java 8 time not showing me the correct time for timezone Etc/GMT+1

Tags: java, java-8, timestamp, java-time

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Etc/GMT+1"));
```

value of this when debugging shows 2019-07-02T14:23:57.463-01:00[Etc/GMT+1]

it should be 16:23, what am i missing .. the clock is 2 hours slow for some reason?

Comment: Hint: "Etc/GMT+1" is the same as "UTC-01" (reversed sign). You should better use the UTC-notation.

Comment: ... which can be seen in the value: `-01:00` vs `[Etc/GMT+1]` (reversed sign)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr

Use a time zone rather than a mere offset.

```
ZonedDateTime.now( 
    ZoneId.of( "Europe/Dublin" )
)
```

## Details

In modern protocols, the number of hours-minutes-seconds in an offset are considered as positive numbers being *ahead* of the baseline (GMT/UTC), and negative numbers as being *behind* the baseline. Some older protocols are the reverse. Your `Etc/GMT+1` seems to be of the reverse style.

The best solution is to use time zones rather than a mere offset. An offset is simply a number of hours-minutes-seconds. A time zone is *much* more. A time zone is a history of past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region.

A time zone has a name in the format of `Continent/Region`. For example, `America/Montreal`, `Europe/Paris`, and `Pacific/Auckland`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Dublin" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Generate a string in standard ISO 8601 format extended wisely to append the name of the zone in square brackets.

```
String output = zdt.toString() ;
```

Most of your business logic, logging, and data  change should be in UTC. To adjust into UTC, extract an `Instant` from your `ZonedDateTime`. Same moment, same point on the timeline, but a different wall-clock time.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

Generate a string in standard ISO 8601 format.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

## Your example

So now we can go back to examine your particular situation.

Let's parse your given string with `[Etc/GMT+1]` as the zone name.

```
String input = "2019-07-02T14:23:57.463-01:00[Etc/GMT+1]" ;
ZonedDateTime zdtInput = ZonedDateTime.parse ( input );
```

Then adjust to UTC.

```
Instant instant = zdtInput.toInstant ();
```

Adjust again into `Europe/Dublin`.

```
ZoneId zDublin = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Dublin");
ZonedDateTime zdtDublin = zdtInput.withZoneSameInstant ( zDublin );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ("zdtInput: " + zdtInput );
System.out.println ("instant: " + instant );
System.out.println ("zdtDublin: " + zdtDublin );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/rphBop).

> zdtInput: 2019-07-02T14:23:57.463-01:00[Etc/GMT+1]
>
> instant: 2019-07-02T15:23:57.463Z
>
> zdtDublin: 2019-07-02T16:23:57.463+01:00[Europe/Dublin]

### Hour 14

Sure enough, we see the day-of-time with `[Etc/GMT+1]` being an hour *behind* UTC (the old reversed meaning of the hours offset) with an hour of `14`.

### Hour 15

UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds) has an hour of `15`.

### Hour 16

The [Dublin time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_the_Republic_of_Ireland) is using Irish Standard Time (IST), UTC +1 rather than [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) at that moment. So we see its hour at `16`, an hour *ahead* of UTC’s `15` hour.

**Crucial:** Understand that all three of these represent the same moment, the very same single point on the timeline. Their wall-clock time differs: three ways to view the same moment in time.

---

By the way, when you want to work with offsets specifically instead of time zones, use the `OffsetDateTime` & `ZoneOffset` classes. The `ZonedDateTime` & `ZoneId` classes are for time zones.